# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS iso for 64-bit intel i7-4700MQ quad core laptop

Tags: 12.04, laptop, multi-core

I have a Lenovo Ideapad with Intel i7-4700MQ processor. Which Ubuntu iso should I download for installation?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want Ubuntu desktop, go to http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop and choose above the big orange button saying 'Ubuntu 12.04 LTS' for 64-bit (since that is your architecture).

Then hit the big orange button saying 'Ubuntu 12.04 LTS'. Next either contribute or scroll down and click on 'Not now, take me to the download'. Then the download for 12,04 LTS 64-bit will start. Note that you can also download the newer Ubuntu 13.10 if you do not necessarily want a LTS version.

If you do not want to contribute you can also use the direct link: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?release=lts&bits=64&distro=desktop&status=zeroc

Ubuntu server is downloaded in a similar way.